# Uploading Images with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, http, filesystems

I'm building a craigslist clone with ASP.NET MVC + SQL Server and I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to go about uploading and storing images. Through my research it seems better to store images in the server's file system rather than on the SQL database, but it can be stored in SQL as varbinary(MAX). Is my assessment correct?

I have a dropzone where you can click and drag multiple images into it and javascript that converts them to an array of blobs. So far I have the submit button make an ajax post request with the array of blobs that I can see in the Controller through Request.Form.Files. However I also want to send over other data from the rest of the form using the ViewModel.

This is the javascript that creates the blob array and posts it with ajax:

```
function buildFormData() {
    //Create and build formData
    formData = new FormData();
    images.forEach((image, index) => {
        formData.append('images[]', image, 'image:' + index);
    })

    //Make post request
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Home/UploadImage',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
    });
}

function setupReader(file) {
    //console.log("File is blob? ", file instanceof Blob); -> true
    images.push(file);
    var name = file.name;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {


        // Create HTML element for image (simplified)
        var previewImg = '<img class="preview-image" src="' + e.target.result + '" />'; 

        //Add img preview element to boxZone
        boxZone.append(previewImg);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readFiles(input) {
    console.log($);
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
        setupReader(input.files[i]);
    }
    console.log("Images: ", images);

}
```

This seems like a good start, I can see the files in Request.Form.Files using the debugger inside of Home Controller UploadImage method, but I bet there's an easier way using the ViewModel.

What's the best way to include a variable-length array of blobs in my View model? Maybe using the [FormFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formfile?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or [FormFileCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formfilecollection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) classes? Or should I just use ajax to post the rest of the form data along with the images like above? Any solution I haven't considered?

Secondly, once the images are on the server I'm not sure how exactly to use the file system to store them. This is a snippet of code from the .NET docs that seems to be [what I'm looking for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-create-a-file-or-folder):

```cs
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(pathString))
{
   for (byte i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
      fs.WriteByte(i);
   }
}
```

These are the questions I'm basically asking:

1. Should I store Images on the file system or SQL database?

2.Should I use Ajax to make the request?
If not:

3. How should I use a ViewModel to send an array of blobs?
4. Should I use FormFile or FormFileCollection classes to represent the images in the view model? Or a custom Image class with a byte[] field to hold the image itself?

Can anyone let me know if I'm going in the right direction, and which methods I should use to upload and store these images that I haven't considered?

Comment: For question 1 I am fairly certain that 99.9% of the opinions [in all these posts before yours](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Should+I+store+Images+in+SQL+Server) is **NO**. Why? Because bloating your database size, log impact, backup size, and I/O in and out of the database and network is tough to justify for the sole benefit of having files and database always be 100% in sync. You can consider FileTable but I think the best answer in almost every use case is to store the file on the file system (which is what file systems are designed for) and the data about that file in the database.

Comment: I work for a software company whose flagship SAAS file storage application stores images that are associated to a given rdbms database record in AWS (S3).  We also create thumbnail previews of images.  In the database we keep pointers (path) to where the image file is located in AWS S3.  That may be an option for you, I don't think it's too complex to implement.